# passing cmd to subprocess.check_output()

Tags: python, sockets, subprocess

Program sets up a command prompt inside of a windows box that a linux box can then use to execute windows commands. So once i have the cmd open in linux and i type dir to see what files are on the windows machine i trigger the exception:

The try block fails and passes back the exception string. If i do a print to see what raw_command is : "built-in function dir"

```python
while "\n" not in cmd_buffer:
    received_bytes=client_socket.recv(1024)
    cmd_buffer += received_bytes.decode()
    response = run_command(cmd_buffer)
    client_socket.send(str.encode(response))

#____run the command output locally and send it back to the client____
def run_command(command):
    raw_command = command.rstrip('\n')
    try:
        output = subprocess.check_output(raw_command, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
    except:
        output = "Command failed \r\n" 
    return output
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `run_command` function works. So the problem is in the way you pass the command to it.
However, when using a `try...except` block you can check the exception raised printing it.

```
import subprocess

def run_command(command):
    raw_command = command.rstrip('\n')
    try:
        output = subprocess.check_output(raw_command, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        output = "Command failed because: " + e.output.decode()

    return output

print(run_command("ls"))
```

Comment: Thank you I will put this in and hopefully be able to better debug it.